# Is there a way to expose the annotation view of a SwiftUI chart?

Tags: ios, swiftui, appium

I am adding accessibility IDs to my application to support automated testing via Appium. For some charts of data, the developers have used SwiftUI structures like BarMark/LineMark/AreaMark etc.

A lot of the data has time on the X axis and whatever data on the Y axis. However, when scanning the page using Appium Inspector, only the entire BarMark shows, with its text being the X axis time label. The Y value has no way to be found/tested that I can figure out.

The annotation (being a view) I expected to be a child element of the BarMark object, but I can't seem to find any way to surface / see it / mark it accessible.

I did try marking the BarMark itself as accessibilityHidden(true) with the hopes the child would show then. This didn't work. In other areas, i was able to solve a "container" issue by using

```
.accessibilityElement(children: .contain)
.accessibilityIdentifier("myContainer")
```

but BarMark does not have access to accessibilityElement.